# different high score types on gamecenter

Tags: sprite-kit, game-center, leaderboard, game-center-leaderboard

I'm making a game using SpriteKit and Swift, I have GameCenter working and keeping track of scores properly, but my question is can I include another category to keep high scores of in that same leaderboard, an example would be like if you were fishing to have a leaderboard that showed who caught the most leaderboard but in another tab show who caught the biggest fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up numerous [leaderboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html) for your app. For example, one leaderboard to track overall scores while also having leaderboards for individual levels. Just make sure each leaderboard has a unique function so not to confuse your players.

Comment: ok, so in my game i have a leaderboards button to display the leaderboard, there is a tab for leaderboards and a tab for challenges, could i just make another tab in the leaderboards screen?

Comment: @IanKunneke- Read the section on "A Game Can Have Multiple Leaderboards" in the docs as well as the parts on a default leaderboard. It's a long read but worth the effort. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13